# window.location not navigating to the correct location after page load is complete

Tags: javascript, php

When my website loads the javascript below it navigates to the correct anchor tag, but when the remainder of the page is loaded (other content via javascript + ajax) a split second later the page is pushed down way beyond the anchor tag. Is there anyway to call window.location (the javascript below) after all other php + javascript is loaded?

```
<script>
window.location = (""+window.location).replace(/#[A-Za-z0-9_]*$/,'')+"#<?php echo $windowlocation; ?>"
</script>
```

Comment: What if you put it in `$(document).ready( function () { // your code});` This gets called after the DOM is ready.

Comment: Let me give that a shot. Thanks. I think I tried it and still experienced the same issue.

Comment: $(window).load(function() {
    // this will fire after the entire page is loaded, including images
});

Comment: rad: Still the same result. It scrolls to the appropriate anchor, additional content loads, and pushes it way beyond the anchor tag.

Comment: @user2744722 Agreed. Ya you need window on load function.

Comment: user: still the same result sadly

Comment: whats weird is after I refresh the page once it works

Comment: Are you getting the images/content with an ajax call and updating with jQuery? Is it async?

Comment: adeneo: still the same result until i refresh the page one time

Comment: So try to move this script after your ajax runs and updates. Perhaps in the success portion. I'm guessing that this script is running before you retrieve the content so you should be able to move it into the success part of the ajax call or after it even..

Comment: There's a lot going on with the page, even after it 'finishes' loading. I can't move it after just one call ajax call. The anchors only work for me if I visit them after the page has loaded

Comment: Pages do not move on their own, your javascript, or ajax success methods must be doing some scroll call. You will need to prevent them from doing that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are loading via ajax, then you can presumably use the call back methods and some kind of method to check for when they are all done.

```
var sectionsLoaded = 0;
var numSections = 1; // number of sections you are loading

$.ajax({ 
    ...
    complete: function(){
        doneLoading();     
    }
});

function doneLoading(){
     sectionsLoaded++;
     if(sectionsLoaded == numSections) {
        //Do something
     }
}
```

Hopefully this answers your question, or is at least in someway useful. Also to be clear the PHP isn't loading. It is being executed on the backend and does nothing to the front end. (you might already know this just the way your question was worded was a bit confusing)

Answer (score 0):

These solutions *should* work:

```
<body onload="script();">
```

or

```
document.onload = function ...
```

or even

```
window.onload = function ...
```